# Neo4j hangs on multiple operations through rest-api, how to configure it?

Tags: node.js, rest, configuration, neo4j, cypher

I have neo4j instance run on 10$/mo digitalocean vps:

1GB / 1 CPU,
30GB SSD DISK,
2TB TRANSFER

I'm using awesome [node library seraph](https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph). But while I tried to save a bit of data (about 10 properties per node) - (around 100 root nodes + 3-5 related nodes for each) after about half of it I start to get econnreset, missing ids and stuff. I guess it's because of wrong configuration/not enough resources.

So how to check what is wrong? What kind of logs to read?

I actually found [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/3546), and added this to configuration:

```
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=10M
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=250M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=500M
```

and there are less errors, but still there is a lot of stuff that is lost due to econnreset.

What should I change? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Neo4j 2.2.2
2. Configure in `neo4j.properties` `dbms.pagecache.memory=250M`
3. Configure in `neo4j-wrapper.conf` the `wrapper.java.maxmemory=512`
4. I'm not sure if seraph uses the REST API to create data or Cyphers remote endpoint, the latter would be preferred.

Please provide your code !!

I presume you can do your whole operation with 500 cypher statements each parametrized with your 10 properties passed to neo as map parameter that you can assign directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would rather not post a code, it's before refactoring, so I'm afraid it won't help:( 

Seraph use rest api. Unfortunately I'm still experiencing those problems. I can post logs though.

Thank you!